# AppleScript to copy a file present in a Restricited Folder to some other location

Tags: macos, applescript, file-copying

I want to copy the files present in a Restricted("No Access") Folder on Mac OS to some other location.

To be precise, on the folder /var/spool/cups (cups is a restricted folder) and i want to copy all the files present inside this folder to some location.

I am able to do this on terminal using sudo sh and the copying the files present in the folder, but i want to do this using an applescript.

Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use a Shellscript inside your Applescript with the administrator privileges attribute :

```
do shell script "cp /var/spool/cups/* some/other/location/" with administrator privileges
```

That way, you will need to enter your username and password from the terminal.

Otherwise, you could use directly the username and password for the superuser inside your Applescript :

```
do shell script "cp /var/spool/cups/* some/other/location/"
   user name "root"
   password "password"
   with administrator privileges
```

Here's official documentation on how it's done :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for addressing by Query chesh. But Actually the first approach is working fine. but when i am trying this with the second solution(with username and password in command line) it shows me a dialog saying "cp: /var/spool/cups/fileName: Permission Denied " .